# Adding interceptor disables directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app with the content of the body containing a directive called layout as shown below.

```
<body>
    <div layout></div>
</body
```

The layout directive contains other directives and is shown below

```
<div id="page-loader" class="fade in"><span class="spinner"></span></div>


<!-- begin #page-container -->
<div id="page-container" class="fade in page-sidebar-fixed page-header-fixed">

    <div header-directive ng-show="1==0"></div>
    <div leftnav-directive ng-show="1==0"></div>
    <div data-ng-view="">
    </div>
    <div footer-directive ng-show="1==0"></div>
</div>
```

I am writing an interceptor for authentication to secure the app. The following line makes the page not load

```
angular
.module('myapp')
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptorService'); // if i comment this line out it works
});
```

If I move the content of the layout directive into the index.html the page loads fine.

```
<body>
<div id="page-loader" class="fade in"><span class="spinner"></span></div>


<!-- begin #page-container -->
<div id="page-container" class="fade in page-sidebar-fixed page-header-fixed">

    <div header-directive ng-show="1==0"></div>
    <div leftnav-directive ng-show="1==0"></div>
    <div data-ng-view="">
    </div>
    <div footer-directive ng-show="1==0"></div>
</div>
</body
```

The reason I am using the directives so I can hide/show the top nav and side nav menus and instead show the login screen (template). SO I can check in the directive code to see if the user is logged in and if they are I would show the other directives.

[This is the interceptor that I am using](https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication/blob/master/AngularJSAuthentication.Web/app/services/authInterceptorService.js)

Any idea if what is going on and how can I resolve it?

Thanks.

EDIT: 
I created a plunker but I cannot seem to make it work. It does not recognize the module helo created in app.js. [Please check it here](https://plnkr.co/edit/mLv4uqp7lhKCJ01GaaS5)

Comment: try removing 'use strict' from top of directive and check ..it causes issues sometime .

Comment: be more selective within interceptor to check path to avoid not loading angular templates

Comment: In the link above the request method appends the token to the header if it is set in local storage. I am assuming that you are suggesting to have this method not append the token if it is a template. So I changed the method to:      it to var _request = function (config) { return config}; That still does not work. Unless I misunderstood you.. please then elaborate..

Comment: can you create a plnkr or jsbin project to show us?

Comment: I added a plnkr, please check the main post

Comment: The Plunker isn't working.